# How to run extjs program

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I've created my first `extjs` program using `sencha` called test and it has an index.html as the main page. I think there should be a way to initialize the app there's no mention of extjs script in index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=10, user-scalable=yes">

    <title>Test</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var Ext = Ext || {}; // Ext namespace won't be defined yet...

        // This function is called by the Microloader after it has performed basic
        // device detection. The results are provided in the "tags" object. You can
        // use these tags here or even add custom tags. These can be used by platform
        // filters in your manifest or by platformConfig expressions in your app.
        //
        Ext.beforeLoad = function (tags) {
            ...
            //};
        };


    </script>

    <!-- The line below must be kept intact for Sencha Cmd to build your application -->
    <script id="microloader" data-app="c0c58612-ec0d-4d6c-99a1-92decf199a29" type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js"></script>

</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain little bit with regards to what you are trying to achieve.?

Comment: I got over this version of problem figured out I need to run sencha command I asked about how to fix it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44851606/unable-to-load-required-framework-extnull-in-extjs

Answer (score 0):

To run a sencha app with extjs use `sencha app watch`

Comment: How do you use this command? What does it do? Could you also provide a link to the documentation?