# Unable to load required framework: ext@null in extjs

Tags: extjs

Setting up extjs and sencha when I ran the app I get error unable to load required framework

```
root@samuel-pc:~/Documents/code/test# sencha app watch
Sencha Cmd v6.5.0.180
[ERR] Unable to load required framework: ext@null
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all you must create `workspace.json` with `sencha workspace init` then add your frameworks into `workspace.json` like:

```
"frameworks": {
  "ext": {
    "path": "ext"
  }
}
```

after that you can run `sencha app install` in order to install requirements and then you can run `sencha app build` and ...